# iCal allows 25,000 events on iCloud. How do I get more?

Tags: icloud, ical

iCal allows 25,000 event entries to be backed up on iCloud. I need more. Is there a way to go over this limit, or segment the iCal file into years, and only activate locally (on my desktop Mac) the years I need at that time? I only need the last 12 months for my iPhone and iPad, but I need the last 10 years of iCal on my desktop. Any solutions? Note: A good solution for me would be to only back up to iCloud my desktop iCal events going back 12 months, and leave my desktop iCal untouched. The problem appears to be when I go online, and iCal attempts to sync with iCloud, and can't - because the desktop iCal has over 25,000 entries.

Answer (score 2):

Why not take the last 9 years of calendar entries, export them as an iCal Archive, then create a new calendar, import those entries, but do not sync to iCal. You can then delete those entries from your daily calendar, while maintaining history in your archive calendar. You can sync this archive calendar to your iPhone via iTunes, rather than iCloud. Of course, you can do this with your 10 years of entries as well, but you will not get the nice benefits from iCloud on your daily calendar.